# k-means clustering algorithm convergence but not a stable convergence using javascript

Tags: javascript

I get convergence, nevertheless, the results are never the same when the algorithm is refreshed.  This occurs even when the data observations is the same dataset.  Can anyone tell me where my methodology is wrong?  For the life of me I can't figure out where the process is wrong.

```
function kmeans2(k, data, canvas, converge) {
    this.canvas = jsHS.GetDimensions(canvas);
    this.k = k;
    this.centroids = []; // Array of centroids
    this.centroids2compare = [];
    this.data = data;
    this.converge = converge;
    this.init();
}
kmeans2.prototype.distance = function () {
    var dif = 0,
        iArray = jsHS.isArray(arguments);
    if (iArray) {
        if (arguments.length > 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i+2) {
                var p0 = arguments[i],
                    p1 = arguments[i + 1];
                dif += Math.pow(p0[0] - p1[0], 2);
                dif += Math.pow(p0[1] - p1[1], 2);
            }
        }
        else {
            var pd0 = arguments[0],
                pd1 = arguments[1];
            dif += Math.pow(pd0[0] - pd1[0], 2);
            dif += Math.pow(pd0[1] - pd1[1], 2);
        }
    }
    return Math.sqrt(dif);
};
kmeans2.prototype.Means = function (Array) {
    var bin = 0;
    [].forEach.call(Array, function(a){
        bin += a;
    });
    return bin / Array.length;
};
kmeans2.prototype.init = function () {
    for (var l = 0; l < this.k; l++) {
        var dataItem = this.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.data.length)];
        this.centroids.push(dataItem);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.centroids.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            var distance = this.distance(this.centroids[i], this.centroids[i - 1]);
            console.log(distance);
        }
    }
    this.clusterCentroids(); // return centroid center after calculating means.
};
kmeans2.prototype.clusterCentroids = function () {
    var points0 = [];
    this.centroids2compare = this.centroids;

    // Find distances between centroid and observations.
    for (var d = 0; d < this.data.length; d++) {
        var cinbin = [];
        for (var c0 = 0; c0 < this.k; c0++) {
            var dis = this.distance(this.centroids[c0], this.data[d]);
            cinbin.push({ 'cid': c0, 'distance': dis });
        }
        var minResult = cinbin.reduce((cid, obj) => {
            return obj.distance < cid.distance ? obj : cid;
        });
        points0.push({ 'id': d, 'datapoint': this.data[d], 'centroid': minResult.cid });
    }

    // Assign observations their appropriate centroid.
    var centroidBin = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < this.k; c++) {
        var cb = [];
        for (var p = 0; p < points0.length; p++) {
            if (c === points0[p].centroid) {
                cb.push(points0[p]);
            }
        }
        centroidBin.push(cb);
    }
    
    // Calculate the mean distance between centroids and its assigned observations.
    this.centroids = [];
    for (var bin = 0; bin < centroidBin.length; bin++) {
        var xAxis = [],
            yAxis = [],
            cb0 = centroidBin[bin];
        [].forEach.call(cb0, function (dp) {
            xAxis.push(dp.datapoint[0]);
            yAxis.push(dp.datapoint[1]);
        });

        var xMean = this.Means(xAxis);
        var yMean = this.Means(yAxis);
        this.centroids.push([xMean, yMean]);
    }

    // Test for convergence. If stored centroids equal new centroids then convergence is achieved.
    if (JSON.stringify(this.centroids2compare) !== JSON.stringify(this.centroids)) {
        this.centroids2compare = [];
        points0 = [];
        this.clusterCentroids();
    }
    else {
        this.converge(centroidBin, this.centroids);
    }
};
window['jsHS']['kmeans2'] = kmeans2;
```

Implementation

```
var k50 = new jsi.kmeans2(5, Array50, canvas, function (con, centroids) {
        var count50 = 0;

        var cmark = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            rad:0,
            clr: null,
            setArc: function () {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.fillStyle = this.clr;
                ctx.fill();
            }
        };
        [].forEach.call(centroids, (c) => {
            cmark.x = c[0];
            cmark.y = c[1];
            cmark.clr = '#0B6623';
            cmark.rad = 25;
            cmark.setArc();
        });
    });
```

This example plots the centroids on a canvas area fine enough but when the browser refreshes the centroids change.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked much at your code, but I know that the k-means algorithm tends to give different results when you run it several times. This is because it's highly dependent on where the first centroids (which are selected randomly) are located.
The algorithm can find a local minimum and get "stuck" there, and terminate.
There's no guarantee that you will find the global minimum the first time you run it.

Comment: ok so there is nothing wrong with my methodology.  Thank you for your response.